# What does $n^d$ is $O(b^n)$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

In my book I came across this part and I'm confused by what it means.

It says:

**we also showed that n is $O(2^n)$. More generally, whenever $d$ is positive and $b$ > 1, we have
$n^d$ is $O(b^n)$**

How does showing n is $O(2^n)$ relate to $n^d$ is $O(b^n)$? And what's an example of $n^d$ is $O(b^n)$?

Comment: Before I explain, do you understand what it means that $n$ is in $\mathcal O (2^n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is concerned with the asymptotic behavior of functions. To say that $n$ is in $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$ means that $2^n$ grows faster (or equally as fast) as $n$. In this case $2^n$ grows much faster than $n$, and hence $n$ is trivially in $\mathcal O(2^n)$.

Now on to your real question.
We are essentially comparing the asymptotic polynomial-type and exponential-type behavior. Consider $n^2$, $n^{4.6}$, $n^{100}$ or in general any $n^d$ where $d>0$ is positive. Now consider as well $3^n$, $1.001^n$, $8^n$ or in general any $b^n$ where $b>1$. To say that $n^d$ is in $\mathcal{O}(b^n)$ means that $b^n$ eventually grows faster than $n^d$. In other words, exponential growth is stronger than polynomial growth.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be a bit confused about big $O$ notation. $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ means that there exists some $C>0$ so that $|f(n)| \leq C|g(n)|$ for all $n$ big enough. What does "big enough" mean? It means that there exists some $N$, possible dependent on $C$, $f$ and $g$ so that the inequality holds for all $n \geq N$. This is a notion of asymptotic dominance.

For instance, $n^3+2n+7 \leq 3^n$ for all $n\geq 4$, so $n^3+2n+7$ is $O(3^n)$. Is $n^3+2n+7$ dominated by anything else? Well obviously $2\cdot n^3$ eventually dominates as $2n^3 - (n^3+2n+7) \geq 0$ for $n\geq 3$. So $n^3+2n+7$ is $O(n^3)$ (note that the $2$ disappears as the $C$ in the definition).
On the other hand $n^3+2n+7 > C n^2$ eventually, for every $C$, so $n^3+2n+7$ is not $O(n^2)$.

Finally, the statement being made in your book is that polynomials are dominated by exponents. $n^d$ is $O(b^n)$. ($b$ here could be $2$, $3$, or any number greater than $1$).

This is follows easily from the fact that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^d}{b^n} < \infty$$
for $d>0$, $b>1$.

Answer (score 0):

When we say that a sequence $a_n$ is $O(f(n))$, we mean, informally, that for large enough $n$, $a_n$ is less (in absolute value) than some fixed multiple of $f(n)$.

For example $3n^2+100$ is $O(n^2)$, because for large enough $n$, $3n^2+100 < 4n^2$, where (in this case) $4$ is the fixed multiple of $n^2$ we chose.  We could have chosen some other multiple: $5, 7, \pi^2$, whatever.  So long as it is finite and fixed, and the above constraint can be shown to hold, it can be used.  For $4$, we see that this is true for $n > 10$: For $n = 11, 3(11^2)+100 = 463 < 484 = 4(11^2)$.  (This is true for all higher $n$, too, though I won't show that here.)

So what the book is saying is that for large enough $n$, $n$ (and in general any finite power of $n$) is less than some multiple of $b^n$, provided $b > 1$: Any polynomial grows slower than any exponential, in the long run.